# Compare points jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como faço um *Jquery* para um *input* de pontos com a função de... (pegar o que tem escrito no *input* e comparar se é maior ou menos com os pontos que ele tem registrado...)

EX:

```
<script> 
    campoTexto.length(pega o que tem escrito e tamanho) e compara se é maior ou menor que numeroPontosCliente.lenght
</script>
```

Comment: Rapaz eu não entendi bem, você quer compara o tamanho do texto digitado com o texto que veio do banco de dados, em uma possível atualização ou algo do genero seria isso ?

Comment: Explica  um pouco melhor, esses pontos seriam o caracter "."?

Comment: Sim, ex: tenho um <p> com 100 pontos "Que está vindo do banco"... em baixo tem um input para eu digitar quantos pontos eu vou usar dos meus 100 pontos que tenho. Preciso do Jquery que não permita avançar com um numero digitado maior que 100 ou menor que 100... entendeu mais ou menos?